# Should fee and price questions go on the Freelancing Stack?

Tags: discussion

Just an opinion, what do you think:

For the same reason Marketing questions should be toned down on GD:SE, I don't see why the "pricing" questions should be mixed with the Graphic Design Stack.

They're very close to critique questions and at this point, might as well accept printing quote questions.

Example:

[How much less to charge as a senior/new graduate for a identity+web package?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41559/how-much-less-to-charge-as-a-senior-new-graduate-for-a-identityweb-package)

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/pricing-for-projects-while-still-in-school

[Pricing for Website Design (Graphics Only)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8666/pricing-for-website-design-graphics-only)

[Graphic Design Pricing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/graphic-design-pricing)

[Concept Design and Card Art freelancing prices](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/concept-design-and-card-art-freelancing-prices)

[What should I do if a potential client claims my pricing is too high?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/what-should-i-do-if-a-potential-client-claims-my-pricing-is-too-high)

Etc. (so many!)

---

The Freelancing Stack has a lot of these questions already but it's mainly used by coders and dev. These guys need some designer friends; the GD:SE pricing questions should be sent there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if and when Freelancing gets out of Beta we could revisit this and decide where to better draw the line. Right now I think the overlap is fine though.

First SE prefers migration to Beta sites be limited:

[Are there precedents to migrate a post to a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site)

Then we've had a discussion about this before though more regarding [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com):

[Should GD business questions remain on GD?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/should-gd-business-questions-remain-on-gd)

Answer (score 9):

They really fit here as well. Most of the pricing issues regarding freelance design are design questions. So they are on topic here as much as they would be at freelance.SE.

Traditionally migration only happens if things are off-topic not merely because they may also be, or be slightly *more* on-topic somewhere else.

---

In addition, it's customarily bad form to migrate multi-stack questions from a full stack site to a beta stack. You don't subtract questions from a full stack to place them on a stack that may *not* survive.

---

What I do commonly is link to questions here at freelance.se, or vice versa, in addition to providing a lead-in sort of answer.

Comment: I don't deny that the question may benefit freelancers... but they are **not** off-topic here. That's my point. And regardless of how long the site's been around, it **is** still a beta site. Some betas last a long time and then fail.. others fail quickly. My opinion, based on the overall content at freelance.se -- it's still a 50/50 shot if it'll survive. 60-70% of the questions are all the same with little value. (just my opinion though).

Comment: Oh and commonly SuperUser.com was where the application questions were posted. And from what I see, many we get here are still migrated to there (if they are good questions).

Answer (score 5):

Scott's answer is spot on, but here's an official answer to your question from [the Stack Exchange Blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> #### Respecting your own community
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to that community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn't be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** - don't blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it - and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to that community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn't be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. Be a bit jealous of your site - don't blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it - and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

That post also explains why we don't just sweep all "tech support" questions over to Super User:

> #### Respecting other communities
>
> - **Don’t migrate poorly-asked or non-constructive questions.** Just close them. If you want to help the asker out by recommending a site where their question would be on-topic, go ahead - but also recommend they read that site’s FAQ first!